# How to make asset exceeds the AppBar?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make this screen in Flutter:

[image]

Is it possible to do this ? I mean make the lizard drawing exit the AppBar and protrude on the main screen?

This is the asset:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You have to make your own custom app Bar

Just do one thing put that all in Stack

```
Stack(
children:[
Position(
top:0,
left:0
child:YourLizardWidget()

),
Position(
top:0,
left:0
right:0
child:YourAppBar()

),
])
```

May be that will work

Comment: Thank you @Rajshekhar Yadav for your quick answer, I try to understand how to do this and will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,200),
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(color: Colors.red,width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,height: 100,),
                Container(width: 100,height: 200,color: Colors.blue,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(color: Colors.amber,),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1. I added a PreferredSize Widget. Its like a container defining the maximum width and height of your appbar.
2. I added `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` property so that the body part will start from the top of the screen instead of starting from below the appbar.
3. Then I simply added my custom appbar as a child property.

This is the result of the above code. (Red container will be your custom appbar and the blue container can be replaced by your asset)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the `drawer` of your application's `Scaffold`.

*Note: if you already use the `drawer`, you may also use the `endDrawer` instead.*

[image]

This solution adds a nice little touch with the slide from left animation. (slide from right for the end drawer)

A few points about the solution:

- In the `AppBar`, I specified the `leading: new Container()` to hide the burger menu and give some space for the lizard.
- In `MyLizardMessage`, I used a `Column` with `verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up` so that my image (using an `OverflowBox` is shown on top of the rounded corners `Container`)

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new Container(),
        title: Text('Mes larfeuils'),
      ),
      drawer: MyLizardMessage(),
      body: MyContent(),
    );
  }
}

class MyLizardMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyLizardMessage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 0.0),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
                'Cupim beef ribs t-bone, shank short loin chicken pork belly prosciutto ribeye hamburger doner pork chop leberkas. '),
          ),
        ),
        IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Container(
            height: 82.0,
            child: OverflowBox(
              maxHeight: 85.0,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/lizard.png',
                height: 85.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyContent({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            'Bacon ipsum dolor amet corned beef pork pork loin, chislic tri-tip picanha beef leberkas short ribs sirloin salami buffalo drumstick. Shankle chislic sirloin pork t-bone short ribs swine sausage hamburger chicken tail. Ham hock doner pancetta, jowl hamburger bacon prosciutto. Strip steak picanha jerky chislic. Strip steak prosciutto beef, pastrami corned beef t-bone frankfurter bacon rump sausage swine filet mignon fatback pork loin. Swine shank short ribs ham porchetta.',
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
              child: Text('Open message dialog')),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text(
            'T-bone venison picanha, corned beef meatloaf bacon buffalo sirloin biltong pancetta strip steak. Ham hock meatloaf tongue pastrami t-bone. Flank prosciutto shoulder chicken, turducken biltong hamburger short ribs beef buffalo brisket chislic filet mignon. Short ribs pork chop jowl jerky, beef ribs sirloin beef kevin landjaeger boudin chislic shankle. Tail pastrami swine drumstick, landjaeger turkey pig ground round.',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is very smart, the problem is, when Drawer is open, you can't use de body screen, if use click a button anywhere, drawer will close.

Comment: Correct. This brings another solution. Wait two minutes.

Comment: Ok if you find a solution with drawer, that should be great for screen which needs animation on them.

Comment: My other solution is not using the App Drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another solution using an `OverlayEntry`.

[image]

This time, you can define an animation when the message appears. But the message is non-modal. You can still use the application UI beneath the message. In the screencast above, I open the message by clicking on the `ElevatedButton` and close it both with the same button and with the close icon within the message. I also show that the `AppBar` action button is also clickable while the message is shown.

#### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new Container(),
        title: Text('Mes larfeuils'),
        actions: [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {})],
      ),
      body: MyContent(),
    );
  }
}

class MyLizardMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onClose;

  const MyLizardMessage({
    Key key,
    this.onClose,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyLizardMessageState createState() => _MyLizardMessageState();
}

class _MyLizardMessageState extends State<MyLizardMessage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> position;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    position = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset.zero)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut));

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: position,
      child: Column(
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Material(
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 0.0),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Cupim beef ribs t-bone, shank short loin chicken pork belly prosciutto ribeye hamburger doner pork chop leberkas. ',
                        style: TextStyle(inherit: false),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => widget.onClose?.call(),
                      child: Icon(Icons.close),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IntrinsicWidth(
            child: Container(
              height: 82.0,
              child: OverflowBox(
                maxHeight: 85.0,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/lizard.png',
                  height: 85.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyContent({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyContentState createState() => _MyContentState();
}

class _MyContentState extends State<MyContent> {
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  bool get _isMessageShown => _overlayEntry != null && _overlayEntry.mounted;

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: width,
          child: MyLizardMessage(onClose: () => _hideMessage()),
        );
      },
      opaque: false,
    );
  }

  _showMessage() {
    _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry);
    setState(() {});
  }

  _hideMessage() {
    _overlayEntry?.remove();
    _overlayEntry = null;
    setState(() {});
  }

  _toggleMessage() => _isMessageShown ? _hideMessage() : _showMessage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            'Bacon ipsum dolor amet corned beef pork pork loin, chislic tri-tip picanha beef leberkas short ribs sirloin salami buffalo drumstick. Shankle chislic sirloin pork t-bone short ribs swine sausage hamburger chicken tail. Ham hock doner pancetta, jowl hamburger bacon prosciutto. Strip steak picanha jerky chislic. Strip steak prosciutto beef, pastrami corned beef t-bone frankfurter bacon rump sausage swine filet mignon fatback pork loin. Swine shank short ribs ham porchetta.',
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _toggleMessage(),
              child: Text(_isMessageShown
                  ? 'Close message dialog'
                  : 'Open message dialog')),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Text(
            'T-bone venison picanha, corned beef meatloaf bacon buffalo sirloin biltong pancetta strip steak. Ham hock meatloaf tongue pastrami t-bone. Flank prosciutto shoulder chicken, turducken biltong hamburger short ribs beef buffalo brisket chislic filet mignon. Short ribs pork chop jowl jerky, beef ribs sirloin beef kevin landjaeger boudin chislic shankle. Tail pastrami swine drumstick, landjaeger turkey pig ground round.',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```